# Does incognito mode prevent cookie-theft attacks?

Tags: cookies

A fresh incognito browser will not have access to any cookies

An active session however, will surely save cookies somewhere so I don't have to login to gmail every time I access gmail.com in the same web-browser session

My question is: does incognito mode prevent 100% of cookie-stealing methods of identify fraud

Comment: What cookie stealing methods are you talking about?  Are you assuming the computer you're on has already been compromised?

Answer (score 1):

## Assumptions

I'm assuming that since you've indicated incognito mode, that you are not talking about attacks where an actor has code running on your machine or remote access.

## Background

Cookies are stored on your computer and linked to a specific website that has requested them.  When you get a cookie from gmail at login, it will be presented to gmail on every subsequent request from that browser session and (as you correctly identified) would not be presented to gmail if you were in incognito.    However, you don't need to be in incognito for your cookie from gmail to be kept secrete from any other website.

## Exploits

For an exploit to get a cookie from your browser that doesn't belong to it, you'd have to break the sandbox. This could get you access to cookies that were not intended for the website.  Since each tab/window of chrome are separate processes, you do get more isolation by using incognito.

## Answer

> does incognito mode prevent 100% of cookie-stealing methods of identify fraud

No, there is nothing you can do to prevent anything 100%.  There is no such thing as being "Secure" only "More Secure".  If someone hits you with a browser escape and a privilege escalation, they can do anything they want on your machine including stealing your cookies.

Comment: Does this mean there are no security benefits in using incognito mode on a private computer (i.e: not even family/friends use it) then?

Comment: Incognito forces chrome to delete browsing history, cookies, site data, or information entered during that incognito session.  So if you're the only one that uses that computer and you don't have malware on the computer or are being attacked through the browser, then no, I can't think of a big security benefit of using Incognito.

Comment: Thanks. I clearly misunderstood its purpose in part

Comment: no problem, glad I could answer your question